# Confusing about phrase which I should use after "than"

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions

> Young people's expenditure in Canada is more evenly split than **in Poland**.

or

> Young people's expenditure in Canada is more evenly split than  **that in Poland**.

I always have the challenge with this grammar; could you please tell me a point to clarify which I should use after "than".

Comment: I don't quite understand you question. Both phrases seem to be alright, except, I would use plural for expenditure: _expenditures_

Comment: @Burglar **expenditure** is not usually used in the plural.

Comment: @WeatherVane - What do you mean "expenditure is not usually used in the plural"?  [There are millions of examples of *expenditures*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=expenditures), unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: @stangdon but are they correct examples? That is like pluralising "weather".

Comment: @WeatherVane - Yes, they are definitely correct usage.  *Expenditure* isn't uncountable like *weather*; it just means "an act of spending money" or "an amount of money that is spent".  For example, ["Household expenditures on cooking oil and shortening decline as household incomes increase..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ExmOp6GIXQC&dq=%22household%20expenditures%20on%22&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=%22household%20expenditures%20on%22&f=false)

Comment: Your first example reads better than the second. There is no need to pluralise *expenditure*. It's optional.

Comment: @stangdon I see we don't speak the same dialect.

Comment: @all- Please also reply me. I am confusing whether I should use "that" after "than" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case your second example would be correct; in the first, you are comparing the subject (expenditure) to a prepositional phrase, which is not the same part of speech. In the second example, "that" acts as a pronoun referencing expenditure.

As an aside, for better flow, I would recommend restructuring this sentence to

> Young people's expenditure is more evenly split in Canada than in Poland.

This makes it clear that the subject is being compared to itself, with different modifiers, as opposed to another object, and places the interchangeable parts of speech (in canada/in poland) close to each other.